# Need help on Func<dynamic,HelperResult>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following statement. I want it to generate the html show below  when I call the commitButton(null)

```
Func<dynamic, HelperResult> commitButton =
(
  @<span class="float-right">
    @using ( Html.BeginForm( "CommitChanges" , "Commit" ) )
    {
      <button type="button" class="commit-button">
        <span></span>
        @ResourceString.CommitChanges
      </button>
    }
  </span>
) ;
```

when I call commitButton(null) 
Expected result should be like

```
<span class="float-right">
 <form action="Commit/CommitChanges" method="POST"><button type="button"   class="commit-button"><span></span> Commit Changes </button></form>
</span>
```

But actual result is

```
  <span class="float-right">
     <button type="button"   class="commit-button"><span></span> Commit Changes </button>
    </span>
```

Comment: You code snippet works fine for me in MVC 5. I see the missing `form` tag. I also see it using the alternate `@helper` syntax, e.g. `@helper commitButton(){ ... }`

Comment: @TimMedora But the point is to see the form render

Comment: Sorry, I mean that I *do* see the form that is missing from your example. It renders correctly.

Comment: I am using mvc4 but I will give a shot to the @helper syntax you suggested